# Core Date Fetch Request on iOS Device

Tags: iphone, ios, database, xcode, core-data

I'm having problem fetching objects from Core Data Model on an iOS device. When using the simulator, objects are fetched successfully, however, on the device the `NSMutableArray` I'm using to get the objects is being empty. When I fetch the objects in `AppDelegate.m` it returns the objects correctly, but when I fetch them in a View Controller the error occurs. I searched a lot the internet and I could not find a solution to the problem. I fetch objects when the application loads, getting this error means that the application will never work. Thanks in advance.

P.S: Do jailbroken iPhones function improperly when testing on them? Also note that I've created another application that uses Core Data and it functions properly, I really don't know what wrong with this one.

```
- (void)loadCategoriesFromDatabase{

categoriesInDatabase = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest alloc];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Category" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"display_order" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortArray];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];

self.categoriesInDatabase = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Please could you post the code for the fetch request in question?

Comment: I've posted the code.

Comment: You may not have initialised your `NSMutableArray` correctly; use `self.categoriesInDatabase` for your first line. Also, check for errors after the `executeFetchRequest` (you are currently passing a `nil` parameter which does not help).

Comment: @RoboticCat, I have used `self.categoriesInDatabase` and nothing changed. Note that when I fetch objects from the `AppDelegate.m` the array returns the objects successfully, when I fetch them from View Controller the app terminates with exception: -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array.

Comment: 1. Which line do you get the error message on? It shouldn't be the setter so where are you calling `objectAtIndex`? 2. If `self.categoriesInDatabase` is empty after the fetch request you have a problem with your fetch and you should check for errors using the error out parameter. What does this give?

Comment: @RoboticCat, I'm not calling `objectAtIndex` Xcode keeps throwing this exception. The error out parameter gave nothing. I used JailCoder to test apps on my jailbroken iPhone, do you think this is the problem? However I built a project using Core Data and it works just fine. I really don't know what to do.

Comment: To have any chance of tracking this error down you need to tell us which line (presumably in the code you posted) is throwing this exception. Which one is it?

Comment: `self.categoriesInDatabase = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];` when I comment this line, the app works fine.

Comment: Are you really initialising your fetch request with this line? `NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest alloc];`. Can you see something missing there?

Comment: @Rog, The problem was with not initializing the `NSFetchRequest` correctly. It's weird how the simulator ran the application without throwing this exception. Thanks for your note!

Answer (score 1):

Try passing an `NSError` pointer to `executeFetchRequest` like this

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSArray* categories = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                            error:&error];
if(error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error debugDescription]);
}
self.categoriesInDatabase = [categories mutableCopy];
```

and post the log with the error.

Comment: I managed to solve this problem by initializing the `NSFetchRequest` correctly. Thanks for your help.